# Extract chain sequences with python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in Python, that describes some kinds of binaries running on various hosts. Some of them are connected each to other. The question is - how can I construct chains from them? If input and output are the same, then binaries are connected.
For example:

```
{"binary1": "bin1", "input": "127.0.0.1:2222", "output": "127.0.0.2:3333", "other_stuff": "....1111..."}
{"binary2": "bin2", "input": "127.0.0.2:3333", "output": "", "other_stuff": "....2222..."}
{"binary3": "bin3", "input": "128.0.0.1:5555", "output": "127.0.0.2:7777", "other_stuff": "....3333..."}
{"binary4": "bin4", "input": "127.0.0.2:8888", "output": "127.0.0.2:4444", "other_stuff": "....4444..."}
{"binary5": "bin5", "input": "127.0.0.1:9999", "output": "127.0.0.2:8888", "other_stuff": "....5555..."}
{"binary6": "bin6", "input": "127.0.0.5:1111", "output": "127.0.0.9:1234", "other_stuff": "....6666..."}
{"binary7": "bin7", "input": "", "output": "127.0.0.1:9999", "other_stuff": "....7777..."}
{"binary8": "bin8", "input": "127.0.0.1:2222", "output": "127.0.0.2:3333", "other_stuff": "....8888..."}
{"binary9": "bin9", "input": "", "output": "127.0.0.5:1111", "other_stuff": "....9999..."}
{"binary0": "bin0", "input": "", "output": "", "other_stuff": "....0000..."}
```

expected output:

```
bin1 -> bin2
bin7 -> bin5 -> bin4
bin9 -> bin6
```

Inputs and outputs are not necessary for each binary.
Finally I will need to make list of chains and to draw them, but it's a bonus :) Does exist some python module that will help to extract sequences and do it fast enough? (Data size is about 10 thousands of binaries).
Thanks in advance!
P.S. Actually I need links to python modules that will help me to solve it (not algorithm), that's all

Comment: No ))) i finished my last homework a 20 years ago.

Comment: Having a dynamic key for the name field is a stupid idea. This subproblem (i.e. how to find `"bin1"` from `{"binary1": "bin1", ..}`) should be solved first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing custom code to do what you ask would be quite simple, but since you specified you want *"links to python modules"*, then my suggestion would be to look into [python-graphs](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/). From the look of it, your problem seems equivalent to build directed graphs...

**EDIT:** This also answers your bonus question about plotting the drawing. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example) example.

Comment: Thanks, @mac. Can you give a hint how to use this complect of dicts with this library? Firstly I need to extract input-output values from all memebres, right?

Comment: @DominiCane - I'm not an expert in python-graphs, but the key-concept is that `IP:port` are the nodes for the graph, and each dictionary defines an edge (see `add_node` and `add_edge` in the linked example). `bin1`, `bin2`, ... are "aliases" of the `input` of the dictionary they are mentioned in, so you will have to keep a mapping `{input(IP:port) : binX}` of your aliases to be used either while defining your graph (easier but more process intensive) or when displaying it (lightweight but it might require to subclass the `Node` class in the library)...